# Vanish and Banish, any difference?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

According to the dictionary the meanings of Vanish and Banish are the same or almost the same. Is there any subtle difference?

> Banish:
>   to expel from or relegate to a country or place by authoritative decree; condemn to exile: *He was banished to Devil's Island*.
>   to compel to depart; send, drive, or put away: *to banish sorrow*.
>
> Vanish:
>   to disappear from sight, especially quickly; become invisible: *The frost vanished when the sun came out.*
>   to go away, especially furtively or mysteriously; disappear by quick departure: *The thief vanished in the night.*

Comment: You may want to [edit] to include the dictionary entries you're working from so we can be more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Vanish* and *banish* are totally unrelated words with entirely different meanings.

- *Vanish* is an intransitive verb meaning "cease to be visible". If I vanish, I suddenly disappear: you can no longer see me.
- *Banish* is a transitive verb meaning "compel [someone or something] to go away". If you *banish* me you order me to depart and never come back; I may or may not obey.

If I do leave, you might say afterwards that I have *vanished*, but that is not how we use the word; *vanish* is typically used of a sudden disappearance, especially if it seems magical.

Answer (score 2):

If you have got the impression that "to vanish" and "to banish" have almost the same meaning you have either a poor dictionary or you have not studied the entries carefully.

"to banish" has a legal basis. In earlier times there was the death penalty or banishment, ie a person was sent out of the country and not allowed to come back.

"to vanish" is simply to disappear. The fog or the clouds can disappear and the sun can come through.

The etymology of the two verbs is totally different. "to vanish" goes back to Latin vanus, adjective, meaning empty, and "to banish" is related with German Bann and verbannen (to sent someone into exile as a punishment).

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/banish?q=banish
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vanish?q=vanish

Comment: Banish is frequently used without the legal meaning.